# Column order on a clustered index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server Clustered Index - Order of Index Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344068/sql-server-clustered-index-order-of-index-question)

I understand that column order in a clustered index is important.

I plan to add a clustered index on 3 columns that are always involved in where clauses -an int, bit and datetimeoffset columns. In addition, the datetimeoffset column stores incremental values.

Would it make sense to have the datetimeoffset column as the first one in the clustered index? Appreciate it.

Comment: You probably don't want to include the `bit` column...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Michael mentioned, the column order in your index is directly linked to what you have in your WHERE clause.

To illustrate this point, as a test I created three tables, each with a different column as the first in the clustered index. Then, I populated them with 10,000 rows of data.

Executing the same SQL query across all three tables yields very different performance results:

```
set statistics io on
set statistics time on

select * from DtFirst where DtCol between '4/1/2010' and '6/1/2010'
select * from IntFirst where DtCol between '4/1/2010' and '6/1/2010'
select * from BitFirst where DtCol between '4/1/2010' and '6/1/2010'

set statistics io off
set statistics time off
```

**Statistics are as follows:**

First table (Date Column first)
Scan count 1, logical reads **3**
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = **0** ms.

Second table (Date Column second)
Scan count 1, logical reads **29**
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = **113** ms.

Third table (Date Column third)
Scan count 1, logical reads **29**
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = **145** ms.

As you can see, querying on the date on the table where the date column is ordered first in the clustered index clearly produces much better results.

Answer (score 9):

Column order is important for all indexes, not just for clustered indexes.

The optimal column order is determined by multiple factors:

Will you ever query this table using just one of these columns, but not the others?  If your index is defined as `ColumnA, ColumnB`... and you perform a query that only filters using `ColumnB`, then that index cannot be used because `ColumnB` is not on the leading edge of the index.

How selective are the values in each of your columns?  The more distinct values contained in the column being indexed, the more effective that index will be.  This is also why you probably won't want to include your `bit` column in your index, since there's only 2 possible values.  The more selective columns are better candidates for being on the leading edge.

Comment: I truly appreciate your reply, it's just that @JebaDaHut put together a nice test so I marked his reply as the answer. Thank you!